# Using the "call" function without evaluating it

Tags: r

I am trying to add a call entry to the object cb.fit.

```
cb.fit = CoxBoost(
    time=clin.mut$SurvMetastasis_Time,
    status=clin.mut$SurvMetastasis_Event,
    x=as.matrix(clin.mut[,-c(1,4,5)]),
    stepno=1000,
    penalty=100
)

cb.fit$call = call(
    "CoxBoost",
    time=clin.mut$SurvMetastasis_Time,
    status=clin.mut$SurvMetastasis_Event,
    x=as.matrix(clin.mut[ ,-c(1,4,5)]),
    stepno=1000,
    penalty=100
)
```

---

though

```
> class(cb.fit$call)
[1] "call"
> names(cb.fit$call)
[1] ""        "time"    "status"  "x"       "stepno"  "penalty"
```

`cb.fit$call` is actually computed values, not an expression.
What did I do wrong?

---

I do not see anything wrong, but if I call the method, then I get true long list values.

I define a generic function and method with

```
  predictSurvProb = function (x, ...) {
                      UseMethod("predictSurvProb", x)
                      }
  predictSurvProb.iCoxBoost = function(x) predict(x, newdata=clin.mut[ ,2:500], type="logplink")

> a = call("predictSurvProb", cb.fit)
> class(predictSurvProb)
[1] "function"
> a = call("predictSurvProb", cb.fit)
> class(cb.fit)
[1] "iCoxBoost" "CoxBoost"
> class(a)
[1] "call"
> a[[1]]
predictSurvProb
> class(a[[2]])
[1] "iCoxBoost" "CoxBoost"
> names(a[[2]])
 [1] "time"             "status"           "stepno"           "penalty"
 [5] "xnames"           "n"                "p"                "event.times"
 [9] "coefficients"     "linear.predictor" "meanx"            "sdx"
[13] "standardize"      "Lambda"           "scoremat"         "logplik"
[17] "call"             "formula"          "terms"            "cause"
> a[[2]]$time
 [1]  146   40  242   69 2749  627  422 2274 2668   67 1695 1554 1839 1699  391
[16]  981   69 1279 1461 1328 1211 1223 1063   34  362 1082  204  765   67  480
[31]  236  301   90 8747  687 5897  366 1558  247 3817 1533 4104  125 1566 3884
[46] 3915   70   48  223 3903 3655   43 3729 3736 2306 3677 1615 3628 3518 3479
[61] 1000 3228   28
```

and so on. All entries in the call object, has actual values.

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually add the call to cb.fit?

Comment: It is in the original post, but the code is formatted in strange way.

cb.fit$call = call("CoxBoost", time=clin.mut$SurvMetastasis_Time, status=clin.mut$SurvMetastasis_Event, x=as.matrix(clin.mut[ ,-c(1,4,5)]), stepno=1000, penalty=100)

Comment: "the code is formatted in a strange way". You formatted it. Take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: cb.fit is "CoxBoost" object.
I am trying to use it as input to pec function in pec package. In order to do so, I need to add an entry "call".
But the call I added is not expression, but actual long list of numbers.

for instance, 
a=10.1
call("round", a)
should be round(10.1)
but in my case, some how it is computed, and gives 10

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `match.call` within a function to return the exact call that was used to call that function.

So calling `match.call()` within the function `someFun(a = b + c, 1234)` will return a call object with that exact content.

You can use this to create a wrapper around the function you want, and return the call along with the actual output of the function:

```
addCall <- function(fun, ...){
  call <- match.call()[-1]

  return(list(call = call, result = fun(...)))
}
```

Which results in the following:

```
> addCall(sum, 1:5)
$call
sum(1:5)

$result
[1] 15

> addCall(sum, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)
$call
sum(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)

$result
[1] 15
```

The `match.call()[-1]` takes the call, and removes the first element. So it would be `addCall(sum, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)`, but if you are only interested in the exact call used to `fun`, the `[-1]` removes the first element (`addCall`), and the second element (`fun`) takes its place.

Comment: I could not fully understand your code. But could you please take a look at my code. I do not see anything wrong, but if I call the method, then I get true long list values.

Comment: The difference is that you construct the call like this `call(function, arguments)`, which evaluates arguments before creating the call, while I do it within the function itself using `match.call`, which creates a call object without evaluating the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> `cb.fit$call` is actually computed values, not an expression.

No, it isn’t. It’s the unevaluated call expression, as your `class(cb.fit$call)` shows. The `names` you show are the argument name of the function call expression.

To use your simplified `round` example:

```
〉 a = 10.1
〉 (x = call("round", a))
round(10.1)
〉 eval(x)
[1] 10
```

— Nothing is evaluated until you actually force evaluation.

… that is, unless you have somewhere overwritten the `call` function in another part of your code. Verify that `call` actually resolves to its original definition, i.e.

```
function(name, ...) .Primitive("call")
```

Comment: I am saying with analog. Of course, if I run
> call("round", 10.1)
round(10.1)
I am saying that in the more complicated function, I am actually getting 10 as output if I analog to this case.

Comment: @Haiying Don’t give analogs then, give *actual* examples. And make them as simple as possible. As it stands, it’s **impossible** to know what you are talking about.